# Show links to archive pages based on custom field values

Tags: custom-field

I have a recruitment website on which I want to display a list of Job Location links. The job location has already been entered into a custom field for each post so I just want to display a list of links that when clicked will show posts with only that custom value entered, ie -

England
Ireland
USA
etc..

Click a country link above and see all of the posts that have the country in question added as a custom field value??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using a custom taxonomy for this, *not* a custom field.  You can sort and list archives based on a taxonomy far more easily than by custom fields.

However, if you want to list based on the custom field, you're going to need to modify the arguments sent to `query_posts()` on your archive page to pass in the `meta_key` and `meta_value` you're searching by.

To add your query variable:

```
add_action('init', 'add_custom_meta_url');
function add_custom_meta_url() {
    global $wp,$wp_rewrite;
    $wp->add_query_var('location');
    $wp_rewrite->add_rule('location/([^/]+)','index.php?location=$matches[1]','top');
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules(false);  // This should really be done in a plugin activation
}
```

Then, your permalinks for the archive will become something along the lines of `http://mycoollocationsite.com/location/england` `http://mycoollocationsite.com/location/ireland` `http://mycoollocationsite.com/location/usa` ... etc ...

Next, you'll need to add whatever value was passed in to your location to the actual query:

```
add_action('parse_query', 'apply_custom_meta_to_query');
function apply_custom_meta_to_query(&$query) {
    if (isset($query->query['location'])) {
        $query->query_vars['meta_key'] = 'location';
        $query->query_vars['meta_value'] = $query->query['location'];
        unset($query->query_vars['location']);            // You don't need this

    }
}
```

I'm assuming you're storing your custom data in a field called `location` ... so change that if I'm wrong.

But this will allow you to filter your archives based on a specific location.  If you want to enable date-based archives with this as well that will require some additional rules in my first code block (right now, this would display a list of *all* posts with a `location` meta_key).

Still, I recommend using a custom taxonomy instead.  It's cleaner, more extensible, and requires less custom coding.  This is also exactly the situation for which custom taxonomies were created ... so please, don't reinvent the wheel ...

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I've never even looked at taxonomies before. Worth having a look at so..I've actually settled on using this plugin to avoid custom code altogether - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-custom-fields-search/